# hide points in mediapipe pose 3d plot

Tags: python, mediapipe

I started work with media pipe pose and i have some problems.

I am trying to highlight only legs point, but on 3d scatter also shows face's and other body's points.

first of all i have the original image with the original points as an example/

[image]

[image]

when i finnaly get only legs point on 2d plot

[image]

but when i try to plot 3d, i get all points.

[image]

I guess, I have to change smth in source code of mediapipe as in 2d plot, but i'm actually dont have any ideas, so I nee your help

here id the code which i use for custom connections

```
IMAGE_FilES=[r"C:\Users\SL-2577\Downloads\b4e1faaf9733adbebf21c568d6b6058d.jpg"]
BG_COLOR = (192, 192, 192) 
with mp_pose.Pose(
    static_image_mode=True,
    model_complexity=2,
    enable_segmentation=True,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5) as pose:
    for idx, file in enumerate(IMAGE_FilES):
        image = cv2.imread(file)
        image_height, image_width, _ = image.shape
        results = pose.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        annotated_image = image.copy()
        annotated_image1 = image.copy()

        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
            annotated_image,
            results.pose_landmarks,
            connections = custom_connections, #  passing the modified connections list
            landmark_drawing_spec=custom_style) # and drawing style 

        cv2.imshow('landmarks', annotated_image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
mp_drawing.plot_landmarks(results.pose_world_landmarks, connections=custom_connections)
```